# How to force the browser to show the most up to date files instead of relying on application cache?

Tags: caching, cross-browser, browser-cache, html5-appcache

It's very important for the website I'm working on to be offline-functional. I'm using a Cache Manifest to store all the files on the application cache, so that takes care of that and all is good and well.

BUT, as I read and noticed myself, the browser first shows the cached version of the site before checking for an update online. Hitting refresh reloads the cache again, with the new cached files this time (or what it had time to update for the swift refreshers).

I'm aware of this fix : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/, where the user is told an update is available and is asked to refresh the page. Not a bad method, but still sketchy for user experience.

Is there any other way to force the browser to show the most up to date files if online? Would cache busting all files manually AND using a cache manifest fix this problem, or will it conflict with the cache manifest and cause problem to the offline functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works well for me:

The URL linking to the web page contains a parameter. If there is ever a change to the page or related files, the url is changed to something like this: http:/ /www.mywebsite.com/mypage.html?v=3 where v=3 is changed depending on updates.

This is a longer fix to implement (finding every page affected by a change & changing all their cache busting links), but the pages at least show what they're supposed to on the first load and the cache manifest still load the update for offline viewing.